# How to handle form submission error without redirecting?

Tags: java, ajax, forms

I have a web form that allows user to enter information and submit. If the user submits a duplicated id field in the form, the form should stay there and prompt error information. However right now if some error information is entered, the page will be redirected to an error page showing "HTTP Status 409 - Conflict". My form is:

```
<form action="/myapp/rest/customer/created" onsubmit="return checkForm();" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Customer name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id" name="id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer DOB:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div><span id="errorDiv" class="errorDiv" ></span></div>
```

And the JavaScript function `checkForm()` is:

```
function checkForm() {

    $.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", function(data, status) {
    if (status === "200") {
        // redirect to destination
        return true;
    } else {
        //display error information in the current form page
        $("#errorDiv").html("<font color=red>ID already exists!</font>");
        return false;
    }
    });
}
```

The backend service is Java REST API which catches the exception if some error information is entered and submitted:

```
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerService {

    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context HttpServletResponse response;

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    CustomerJDBCTemplate dbController = (CustomerJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("customerJDBCTemplate");


    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Path("created")
    public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id,
            @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("dob") Date dob)
            throws ServletException, IOException, WebApplicationException {
        URI uri = URI.create(uriInfo.getPath());
        Response r;


        r = Response.created(uri).build();

        try {
            dbController.create(id, name, dob); //This may throw exception.

        request.setAttribute("name", name);
        request.setAttribute("dob", dob);
        request.setAttribute("id", Integer.valueOf(id));
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/confirm.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(409);
        }

        return r;
    }
}
```

So why does the page always redirect to the error page showing "HTTP Status 409 - Conflict" if user submits error information? Why the ajax form validation `checkForm()` doesn't work here?

Comment: is jquery script added to the page and loaded?

Comment: yes, jQuery script is added in the <head> section.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$.post(` is asynchronous and your `return`s have no effect. The form is always submitted to server and line `throw new WebApplicationException(409);` causes error code response.

**Update:**

@WouterH's suggestion should work. Make sure that you see alerts at the right moments:

```
function checkForm() {
    $.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", function(data, status) {
      if (status === "200") {
        alert("post success");
        // redirect to destination
      } else {
        alert("post error");
        //display error information in the current form page
        $("#errorDiv").html("<font color=red>ID already exists!</font>");
      }
    });
    alert("form posted");
    return false;
}
```

**Update 2:**

```
function checkForm() {
    $.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", function(data, status) {
      alert("post handler, status=" + status); 
    });
    alert("form posted");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach again but still redirects to the error page. There is no "alert" message box poping up when there is an submission error. Does it have something to do with the server-side code? I've just updated my server-side REST code as shown above.

Comment: do you see "form posted" message? As long as you return `false` from `onsubmit` handler, the page should stay as it is. Try the code from my second update.

Comment: I tried your approach again but still didn't work. It didn't show any "form posted" message or any other message, regardless of whether form submission is successful or not. It either goes to an error page or to a JSP page (confirm.jsp as specified in the server-side code) if succeeded. Very strange behavior.

Comment: This means that `checkForm` is not executing, the form gets submitted normally, and all is done server-side. There may be a javascript syntax error in the page. Remove all code from `checkForm` but the single alert.

Comment: That's right. The JS code `checkForm()` in `onsubmit` is not executing no matter whether the form submission is successful or not. I removd all code from `checkForm` except the alert but it still doesn't show any alert message. So it seems that server side does everything.

Comment: By the way, the way you are using `$.post()`, it will not carry any form data. You need `$.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", $("form").serialize(), function(data, status) {...});`

Comment: OK, I changed to use `$("form").serialize()` but still no effect. I guess the `@FormParam` in server-side code automatically injects entered form fields into the Java method `createCustomer`.

Comment: They do, only if the values are part of the request. But this has no bearing on the fact that javascript `onsubmit` event handler is not executing. I suggest, you create a small "does-nothing" page with a form and make sure that you are able to assign an `onsubmit` code that actually runs.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkForm method is asynchronious. Or rather, it makes use of an asynchronious function, $.post. $.post makes use of AJAX, and AJAX stands for Asynchronious Javascript And XML. What this means, is that the function returns immediately ($.post) before completing its task and calling the callback.

You will always want to block form submission, since you are submitting using AJAX. You can do this by returning false within checkForm, instead of within the callback provided to $.post.

For example:

```
function checkForm() {
    $.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", function(data, status) {
        if (status === "200") {
            // redirect to destination
        } else {
            //display error information in the current form page
            $("#errorDiv").html("<font color=red>ID already exists!</font>");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it still redirects to error page if error information is submitted.